# OpenCV iOS improve text quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, opencv

Output Image
[image: Output image]
Code applied :

```
            original = [MAOpenCV cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:_sourceImage];
            cv::GaussianBlur(original, original, cvSize(11,11), 0);
            cv::adaptiveThreshold(original, original, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);

            _adjustedImage = [MAOpenCV UIImageFromCVMat:original];

            original.release();
```

You can see there is very non sharped text. can we fill those white patches inside the character?so that our text can visible properly to do OCR. I am following [MAImagePicker](https://github.com/mmackh/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF/issues/4) project.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try using the Dilate and Erode techniques described here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html
Recognising the text seems very hard because of its quality, as it hard even for humans (knowing the context of the text). Perhaps the dilate and erode methods could make it a bit more clear at least.